# last-child selector when adding content with css

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to build a selection on the side of a container. Visually its represented by having dots below each other where the currently active one grows in size and it slowly switches to another one after some time.

The does have lines going down from one dot to the next. I want the last dot to not have a line. I tried using the last-child selector but couldnt get the hang of it. I tried any combination of last-child and after I could think of but Im at my wits end.

This is the current code for the dots:

```
.show-dots {
    .slide-dots {
        position:absolute;
        top:30%;
        left:15%;
        width: 40px;
        z-index:98;
        
        .slide-dot {
            width:40px;
            margin: 0 auto 35px auto;
            text-align: center;
            
            a {
                display:block;
                text-align:center;
                width:40px;
                
                .slide-dot-style {
                    width:7px;
                    height:7px;
                    border-radius:15px;
                    display:block;
                    background-color:@white;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
                    
                    &::after {
                        content: "";
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 50%;
                        background-color: @white;
                        height: 35px;
                        width: 1px;
                        top: 0;
                    }

                    &.active {
                        width:15px;
                        height:15px;
                        
                        &::after {
                            height: 42px;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CSS on its own, without the HTML structure it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, when you ask this kind of question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the :not(:last-child) selector to target all points except the last point. See Example:

```
.show-dots {
    .slide-dots {
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        left: 15%;
        width: 40px;
        z-index: 98;

        .slide-dot {
            width: 40px;
            margin: 0 auto 35px auto;
            text-align: center;

            a {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                width: 40px;

                .slide-dot-style {
                    width: 7px;
                    height: 7px;
                    border-radius: 15px;
                    display: block;
                    background-color: @white;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);

                    &::after {
                        content: "";
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 50%;
                        background-color: @white;
                        height: 35px;
                        width: 1px;
                        top: 0;
                    }

                    &:not(:last-child) {
                        &::after {
                            height: 35px;  
                        }
                    }

                    &.active {
                        width: 15px;
                        height: 15px;

                        &::after {
                            height: 42px;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```